# webflux.fn with coroutines: Returning a flow indicates success but has no content in the body; Why is it empty?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, arrow-kt

I have been tasked with migrating some Reactor based services to webflux.fn + coroutines.
The service generates a png compass image.  I see the bytes of the compass before they are returned to Postman from the new coroutine based service.  In Postman, I see that the request was successful, but no content in the body; empty.  I've been unable to figure out why the Flow is returning success but no content.  I'd appreciate your suggestions...

Thanks

```
>>>REQUEST
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8080/api/compass" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
-d $'{}'
```

```
>>>RESPONSE
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-Type: image/png
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
connection: close
```

```
>>>WEBFLUX.FN ROUTER
@Component
class MyRouter(private val myHandler: MyHandler) {
    @Bean
    fun routes(myHandler: MyHandler) =
        coRouter {
            accept(APPLICATION_JSON).nest {
                ("/api".nest {
                    POST("/compass", myHandler::generateCompass)
                })
            }
        }
}
```

```
>>>HANDLER
override suspend fun generateCompass(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
    return myService
        .generateCompass(request.awaitBody())
        .fold({ throw it }, {
            ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
                .bodyAndAwait(it)
        })
}
```

```
>>>SERVICE
   suspend fun generateCompass(request: CompassRequest
    ): Either<Throwable, Flow<ByteArray>> =

        Either.Right(
            flow<ByteArray> {
                MapCompass(request)
                    .exportToRaster()
                    .map { it.toByteArray() }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I discovered that there is a difference between using flow {} and flowOf().  I needed to use flowOf() to stream my ByteArray.  All is well, now...

```
>>>CORRECTED CODE
    private fun generateMapCompass(
        request: MapCompassRequest
    ): Either<Throwable, Flow<ByteArray>> =
        MapCompass()
            .exportToRaster(MediaType.Png, ImageDimension(1.0f, 1.0f))
            .map { baos ->
                baos.toByteArray()
            }
            .map { flowOf(it) }
```

```
/**
 * An analogue of the [flow] builder that does not check the context of execution of the resulting flow.
 * Used in our own operators where we trust the context of invocations.
 */
@PublishedApi
internal inline fun <T> unsafeFlow(@BuilderInference crossinline block: suspend FlowCollector<T>.() -> Unit): Flow<T> {
    return object : Flow<T> {
        override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
            collector.block()
        }
    }
}
```

````
/**
 * Creates a flow that produces values from the specified `vararg`-arguments.
 *
 * Example of usage:
 * ```
 * flowOf(1, 2, 3)
 * ```
 */
public fun <T> flowOf(vararg elements: T): Flow<T> = flow {
    for (element in elements) {
        emit(element)
    }
}
````